# How to rank table rows group wise in SQL Server without using RANK() or rownums function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to rank the below table by grouping the sid and ranking the groups through marks in SQL Server.

Refer to the following table and answer the questions:

Marks:

```
sid     sub     marks
----------------------
53666   sub1    30
53666   sub2    15
53666   sub2    20
53667   sub1    10
53667   sub2    40
53667   sub3    20
```

Using windowing/analytical functions give a query for achieving the following output:

```
sid     sub     rank
---------------------
53666   sub1    1
53666   sub2    3
53666   sub2    2
53667   sub1    3
53667   sub2    1
53667   sub3    2
```

Comment: Use Row_Number()

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why are you repeating yourself? Why your title mentions that you don't want to use `RANK()` while the text in your question clearly indicates that window functions should be used?

Comment: but for my understanding I do want to rank without Row_Number or RANK() function. can you help me?

Comment: @shubhamborghare You may use windowed `SUM()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this query

```
SELECT *, CASE 
            WHEN mark >= 30 THEN 1 
            WHEN mark <= 15 THEN 3
            ELSE 2
            END
FROM [dbo].[Q1]
```

output

```
id          sid         sub        mark        
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           53666       sub1       30          1
2           53666       sub2       15          3
3           53666       sub2       20          2
4           53667       sub1       10          3
5           53667       sub2       40          1
6           53667       sub3       20          2
```

Comment: your welcome if you wants to add another rank you can add some range in case statement

Comment: @MahdiRahimi If I understand the question correctly and the requirement is to use _windowing/analytical functions_, this approach is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with windowed `SUM()` with the appropriate `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Marks (
   sid int,
   sub varchar(4),
   marks int
)
INSERT INTO Marks
   (sid, sub, marks)
VALUES
   (53666, 'sub1', 30),
   (53666, 'sub2', 15),
   (53666, 'sub2', 20),
   (53667, 'sub1', 10),
   (53667, 'sub2', 40),
   (53667, 'sub3', 20)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   sid, sub, SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY marks DESC) AS rn
FROM Marks
ORDER BY sid, sub, marks
```

Result:

```
------------------
sid     sub     rn
------------------
53666   sub1    1
53666   sub2    3
53666   sub2    2
53667   sub1    3
53667   sub2    1
53667   sub3    2
```

Comment: Your output is different from the output shubham borghare want

Comment: @shubhamborghare  If I understand the question correctly and the requirement is to use _windowing/analytical functions_, this approach helps.

Comment: @MahdiRahimi No, it;s not. It just needs an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: order by ?? on which col you mean?

Comment: @MahdiRahimi `ORDER BY sid, sub, marks` for example.